# Storyboard transition without any touch(i.e IBOutlet)

Tags: iphone, storyboard

I am using storyboard,in which i have three view controllers. I want to go to 2nd view controller from first without any touch(so i used timer .) 
I added following code to timers method:

[self presentModalViewController:anyViewControllerRef animated:YES];
or
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:anyViewControllerRef animated:YES];

but both the times i got blank screen after timers interval (even i got the logs perfectly, means the logs which i added in 2nd ViewControllers class but no visuals correctly)

What should i add to timers method to perform scene transition?(so able to see whatever i have added on next ViewController)

Comment: Got the solution. Need to add identifier to next view controller and following code in timers method : anyViewControllerRef = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifierName"]; //must needed line else u'll get black screen
   
    [[self navigationController ] pushViewController:anyViewControllerRef animated:YES];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add identifier to next view controller and following code in timers method :

anyViewControllerRef = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifierName"];

[[self navigationController ] pushViewController:anyViewControllerRef animated:YES]

Answer (score 1):

Just for your own reference, the reason why this was not working for you was because you were "creating" a viewcontroller of whatever type you had and showing this "newly created" controller, of course this one doesnt have any visuals on it because the interfacebuilder controller is NOT linked to this one.

Your solution means that instead of creating an instance of the anyViewControllerRef you are asking the storyboard to give you the one it holds (the one with the visual elements you added).

By the way almost 90% of the time you want to present modally a view controller under ios for iphone, push is only used for ipad or for navigationviewcontroller if i remember correctly.